# In Python, how do you execute objects that are functions from a list?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new at Python and can't seem to get this to work. I have a list which has an imbedded list of objects which are the names of functions and I need to execute the list of objects. I have functions that call lists of functions. I want to change this so I can call the list of functions directly without calling another function.

```
validActions=[
  ['Refresh','Environment Refresh',Refresh],
  ['Retire','Environment Retire Storage',
    [ doStatusDecommission,
      doPauseJobBeforeStart,
      doRetireStorage,
      doStatusDisconnected]],
  ['Provision','Environment Provision Storage',Provision]
]

def updateEnv(ctx):
  for actionVal,actionDesc,actionFunction in validActions:
    if ctx["newAction"] == actionVal:
      actionFunction()
```

This works if I'm calling "Refresh" or "Provision" as they are functions. However, this does not work when I call the list for "Retire" and the error message is

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: Why can't you have an embedded list of references to the functions themselves?

Comment: You can make another function which calls all 4 of those functions.

Comment: @Asad: They already are; the title is inaccurate.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I admit I just skimmed the body, but looking at it now I'm even more confused. Some of those are strings and some are references (presumably to functors). Is there a pattern? EDIT: I see it now.

Comment: @Asad: The third element.

Answer (score 3):

You can still call each function in the list. If you make *all* entries lists then it becomes much easier to handle both cases:

```
validActions=[
    ['Refresh','Environment Refresh', [Refresh]],
    ['Retire','Environment Retire Storage', [
        doStatusDecommission,
        doPauseJobBeforeStart,
        doRetireStorage,
        doStatusDisconnected
    ]],
    ['Provision', 'Environment Provision Storage', [Provision]]
]

def updateEnv(ctx):
    for actionVal, actionDesc, actionFunctions in validActions:
        if ctx["newAction"] == actionVal:
            for action_function in actionFunctions:
                action_function()
```

If all you are doing is finding the **one** action that matches `ctx['newAction']`, you'd be better off using a dictionary and look up the `actionDesc` and `actionFunctions` items from that *directly:

```
validActions = {
    'Refresh': ('Environment Refresh', (Refresh,)),
    'Retire': ('Environment Retire Storage', (
        doStatusDecommission,
        doPauseJobBeforeStart,
        doRetireStorage,
        doStatusDisconnected
    ),
    'Provision': ('Environment Provision Storage', (Provision,)),
}

def updateEnv(ctx):
    actionDesc, actionFunctions = validActions[ctx["newAction"]]
    for action_function in actionFunctions:
         action_function()
```

Comment: I think the OP is also wasting resources by using a list and looping through it to find a single "actionVal", determined by `ctx["newAction"]`. The OP should use a dictionary of lists of functors.

Answer (score 1):

Make all of them lists and then iterate over the list executing each in turn.

```
for actionVal,actionDesc,actionFunctions in validActions:
  if ctx["newAction"] == actionVal:
    for actionFunction in actionFunctions:
      actionFunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to have each list end with a list of functions, even if the list only has one element

```
validActions=[
  ['Refresh','Environment Refresh', [Refresh]], #note brackets around Refresh
  ['Retire','Environment Retire Storage',
    [ doStatusDecommission,
      doPauseJobBeforeStart,
      doRetireStorage,
      doStatusDisconnected]],
  ['Provision','Environment Provision Storage',[Provision]]
]

def updateEnv(ctx):
  for actionVal,actionDesc,actionFunctions in validActions:
    if ctx["newAction"] == actionVal:
      for func in actionFunctions:
        func()
```

---

Or make a new function which calls all 4 of those functions

```
def retireFunctions():
  doStatusDecommission()
  doPauseJobBeforeStart()
  doRetireStorage()
  doStatusDisconnected()

validActions=[
  ['Refresh','Environment Refresh',Refresh],
  ['Retire','Environment Retire Storage', retireFunctions],
  ['Provision','Environment Provision Storage',Provision]
]
```

---

Or a final option is a type test (not recommended)

```
def updateEnv(ctx):
  for actionVal,actionDesc,actionFunction in validActions:
    if ctx["newAction"] == actionVal:
      if callable(actionFunction):
        actionFunction()
      else:
        for func in actionFunction:
          func()
```

Comment: I already had the solution where I have one function call the other functions but I am moving away from that so I can keep track of all the functions being called in one place. Ending each list with a list of functions works for the implementation I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to fill my answer with your defined list to make it look longer. I'll use the same list you defined.

```
def updateEnv(ctx):
    for actionVal,actionDesc,actionFunctions in validActions:
        if ctx["newAction"] == actionVal:
            try:
                [func() for func in actionFunctions]
            except TypeError:
                # not iterable
                actionFunctions()
            except Exception as e:
                # iterable, unexpected errors
                print e
                pass
```

If you can modify the data structure, I suggest the following:

```
validActions={
  ('Refresh','Environment Refresh') : {Refresh},
  ('Retire','Environment Retire Storage'):
    { doStatusDecommission,
      doPauseJobBeforeStart,
      doRetireStorage,
      doStatusDisconnected } ,
  ('Provision','Environment Provision Storage'):{Provision}
}
```

Your functions are generally method descriptor, which are immutable. Using set as container of your function can greatly reduce time cost in iterating and counting.

By using dictionary as top-level container with tuple keys, you can accurately map your input to output. What does that mean? It means:

```
def updateEnv(ctx):
    [[func() for func in value] if ctx["newAction"] == key[0] 
     else None
     for key, value in validActions.items()]
```

Even more efficiently, if you know actionDecs is unique to actionVal, use two separate mappings:

```
validActions = {
   'Refresh' : {Refresh},
   'Retire':
      { doStatusDecommission,
       doPauseJobBeforeStart,
       doRetireStorage,
       doStatusDisconnected } ,
   'Provision' : {Provision}
}

actionsDescs = {
    'Refresh': 'Environment Refresh'
    'Retire': 'Environment Retire Storage'
    'Provision' : 'Environment Provision Storage'
}
```

If you need to description from abbreviation, call for example:

```
actionsDescs['Refresh']
```

And you function iteration becomes:

```
def updateEnv(ctx):
    [func() for func in validAction[ctx["newAction"]]]
```

Feel free to comment if you have specific need or question on this.

Answer (score -1):

To get function by name

If functions defined in this module:

```
globals().get(actionFunctionName)(args)
```

If in other module or class:

```
getattr(class_or_module,actionFunctionName)(args)
```

Comment: The objects are *already* functions. They are *not* strings naming functions. The title is misleading.

Comment: Question was rewrited few times.

Comment: I adjusted the title after reading the question; I made that edit *after* I commented on your answer. It was the *only* edit made to the question.